# Buildfile:build.xml does not exist

Tags: ant, installation, voltdb

I have installed Ant  as i could use ant -version where it shows Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017.i use Ubuntu 16.04 ,After I decompress voltdb,modify environment variables ,in terminal,import Ant.then the problem shows.maybe I need to illustrate I have never use it ,no data in voltdb.
I want to get it down.

Answer (score 0):

the instructions for building VoltDB from source are here: https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Building-VoltDB

If you can be more specific about what steps you have taken, we might be able to help.  You can also contact us on our [user forums](https://forum.voltdb.com/forum), or public [Slack channel](http://chat.voltdb.com/).

You can also [download](https://www.voltdb.com/try-voltdb/) VoltDB pre-built and try it free for 30 days.

Comment: Thanks for you help.i have solve it although I don't why.i change the enterprise voltdb to community voltdb.Then,it is over.a strang answer. After that try to init voltdb,it shows me fail to find jar.so I tar the link package of maven,modify the environment.its bad for nothing changed.i don't know what to